# Spring WebServiceTemplate Interceptor for adding security header

Tags: spring, spring-ws, wss4j, webservicetemplate

I am trying to add a SOAP:Header with wss4j authentication for my outbound SOAP service.

Below is my WebServiceTemplate  and interceptor configuration

```
<bean id="securityHeader"
    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="securementActions" value="UsernameToken" />
    <property name="securementUsername" value="uname" />
    <property name="securementPassword" value="password@123" />
    <property name="securementPasswordType" value="PasswordText" />
    <property name="securementUsernameTokenElements" value="Nonce Created" />
</bean>`

<bean id="webService" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
    <property name="messageSender">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender">
            <!-- <property name="credentials" ref="credentials" /> -->
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptors">
    <list>
        <ref bean="securityHeader" />
    </list>
</property>
    <property name="defaultUri"
        value="https://test.test.com/ws/service/test" />        
    <property name="marshaller" ref="fmarshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="forwardunmarshaller" />
</bean>
```

But when the outbound call happens, its not adding the SOAP security header.`webService.marshalSendAndReceive("http://localhost:8088/mockBinding",request);`

Comment: Can't see a problem here. Can you try if specifying the bean definition directly; (without a ref) works?

Comment: Is the configured `WebServiceTemplate` actually the template you are using?

Comment: Will there be an issue with the wss4j and spring version im using?

Comment: After removing the reference and adding the bean declaration within the interceptor property,  I am getting this exception. org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: SOAP Envelope can not have children other than SOAP Header and Body

Comment: Can you please update your question with the Spring-WS and Axiom version you are using?

Comment: Spring-WS version is 2.2.2.RELEASE and also I found spring-security-core-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar inside my war. Will this cause problem?

Answer (score 0):

Below changes did the trick for me.

1. Changing the SOAP version to 1.1
2. Defining the bean declaration inside interceptor instead of referencing it.
3. Use a web service message callback.